# Node.js - Function not working when exported

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, module.exports

Good day everyone,

First off, thanks for always being such an amazing community. You all really are helping me a ton with learning and bettering my programming and development!

I have a small question related to the module.exports within Node.js. The function below runs with no issues when called on directly:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const {nanoid} = require('nanoid')

const createStormDB = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try{
            const id = nanoid(4)
            const date = new Date() // Create date string for file naming
            let dateString = `${date.toISOString().split('T')[0]}` // Create date string for file naming
            let fileName = `${dateString}_deals_${id}.stormdb` // Create date string for file naming
            fs.openSync(`../StormDB/${fileName}`, 'w')

            resolve(fileName)
    
        }catch(err){
            reject(err)
        }
    })
}

module.exports = createStormDB
```

It creates a file with a specific name within in specific folder. But when I use `module.exports = createStormDB` I am greeted with the following error:

```
(node:12516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../StormDB/2021-07-19_deals_gYmJ.stormdb'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)
    at C:\Node\Pipedrive-Connector\PipeDriveRequest\scripts\createStormDBFile.js:11:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at createStormDB (C:\Node\Pipedrive-Connector\PipeDriveRequest\scripts\createStormDBFile.js:5:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Node\Pipedrive-Connector\PipeDriveRequest\play.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
```

Is there something I am misunderstanding when it comes to exporting modules? I'm importing this module using the `require` option! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: There is no point on wrapping `fs.openSync()` in a promise.  And, you shouldn't be opening a file and then doing nothing with the resulting file handle.  That will just leak file handles.

Answer (score 1):

The `..` relative path in the function is relative to the calling scripts current working directory, not the directory the file is in.

Assuming from your path setup and description the database is in: `C:\Node\Pipedrive-Connector\PipeDriveRequest\StormDB`

If you want the database path to remain relative to the javascript file containing the function, use `__dirname`

```
const path = require('path')
const db_path = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'StormDB', filename)
fs.openSync(db_path, 'w')
```

Comment: As a side note, [`fs.promises.open`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_open_path_flags_mode) is the promise version of the function.  Creating a promise for `openSync` seems unnecessary

Comment: Not to mention that `fs.openSync()` isn't even asynchronous so there's zero reason to use it with a promise.